# Remove Carriage Return & Line Feed from Concatenated Trailer Record in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, notepad

I have a resultant dataset from a SQL query run in SSMS that includes a 1-row trailer record that exports & saves to Notepad in .txt format.  The trailer record, however, automatically includes hex control to include a line feed/carriage record after the concatenated field (750 characters) that is the trailer record.  How can I eliminate this from the end of the trailer record prior to export to .txt format?  File must not include any empty rows.

I've tried the following line code in the SELECT statement for my trailer record that seems to be the common fix for a situation like this:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE('T'+CAST(RIGHT(REPLACE(STR(COUNT(*)),' ','0'),9) AS VARCHAR)+SPACE(740),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
```

It, however, still includes line feed & carriage hex character upon export in .txt format.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE('T'+CAST(RIGHT(REPLACE(STR(COUNT(*)),' ','0'),9) AS VARCHAR)+SPACE(740),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
```

Expected outcome is for the file to not include the 0D & 0A byte characters shown in the included hex view of the exported doc.

[image: HEX VIEW OF EXPORTED .TXT FILE]

Comment: There is no CR or LF in that expression.   I imagine they are being generated by the process that is writing the value to the text file.   How are you creating the text file?

Comment: David,
 I am currently right-clicking on the resultant data displayed in SSMS after running my query in 'Results to Grid' mode.  I then choose 'Save Results As' and save a .txt formatted file that includes the problem line feed & carriage return controls...Thanks.

Comment: Try it with something simpler.  What happens when you try   select 'x'   and do the same?   I think it's the save process that's adding the CR/LF.

Comment: @DavidDubois The OP may not have been clear - the CR and LF... are 0D and 0A. Note this query: `SELECT CAST(CHAR(13) AS VARBINARY(2)), CAST(CHAR(10) AS VARBINARY(2))`.. (I could me misinterpretting what you are saying though)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from what you've said (and the following comments) if the problem is at the SQL level or outside it when the text file is created. Either way, you can solve this using [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) can help (The link includes a VARCHAR(MAX) version as well which is slower than the 8K version but still nasty fast.)

I often automate to process of manually updating build scripts by importing them them via OPENROWSET (or whatever), modifying the text then writing the results to a new file  replacing the old one (using BCP). Below is some code to help you understand how I can use an NGrams function to solve this.

**Analysis:**

```
DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(8000) =
'blah blah blah.... ;
blah blah     .... ;
blah blah blah.... ;
 ...;';

SELECT
  ng.position,
  ng.token,
  charValue   = ASCII(ng.Token),
  binaryValue = CAST(ng.token AS VARBINARY(2))
FROM samd.NGrams8K(@someString,1) AS ng;
```

**Returns (truncated for brevity):**

```
position             token     charValue   binaryValue
-------------------- --------- ----------- -----------
1                    b         98          0x62
2                    l         108         0x6C
3                    a         97          0x61
4                    h         104         0x68
5                              32          0x20
6                    b         98          0x62
...
...
68                   .         46          0x2E
69                   .         46          0x2E
70                   .         46          0x2E
71                             32          0x20
72                   ;         59          0x3B
73                             13          0x0D
74                             10          0x0A
75                             32          0x20
76                             32          0x20
....
```

Notice lines 73 & 74? Those are the two characters you want to remove: CHAR(13) & CHAR(10) AKA *0D* and *0A*. You want to remove those.

Using NGrams or NGrams8k you can get the position of the last LF+CR by locating the last CHAR(13).

```
DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(8000) =
'blah blah blah.... ;
blah blah     .... ;
blah blah blah.... ;
 ...;';

SELECT MAX(ng.position)
FROM   samd.NGrams8K(@someString,1) AS ng
WHERE  ASCII(ng.Token) = 13;
```

**Returns:** 73

Note that I'm using a variable (@someString) for demonstration, if the GUI is adding the final LF/CR then you'll have to import that file and assign the contents to a variable.

```
DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(8000) =
'blah blah blah.... ;
blah blah     .... ;
blah blah blah.... ;
 ...;';

-- Use STUFF to remove the last CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
DECLARE @newString VARCHAR(8000) = 
STUFF(
  @someString,
  (
    SELECT MAX(ng.position)
    FROM   samd.Ngrams8K(@someString,1) AS ng
    WHERE  ASCII(ng.Token) = 13
  ),2,'');
```

This code ^^^^ removes the final LF/CR.

UPDATE:

I just saw david's response; if that's the case, you can use my solution to pull the file in, change the contents and write a new file. Below is an example of how I do this (not perfect but it works).

```
CREATE PROC dbo.FileTransform_clean
  @sourceFile NVARCHAR(500),
  @destFile   NVARCHAR(500),
  @badText    NVARCHAR(1000),
  @cleanup    BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
  -- 0. Prep
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @sourceFile = TRIM(@sourceFile);

    DECLARE @pos  SMALLINT       = CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@sourceFile));
    DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(4000) = SUBSTRING(@sourceFile,1,LEN(@sourceFile)-@pos),
            @file NVARCHAR(4000) = SUBSTRING(@sourceFile,LEN(@sourceFile)-@pos+2,4000);
    DECLARE @t TABLE (subdirectory NVARCHAR(4000), depth TINYINT, [file] BIT);

    INSERT @t(subdirectory, depth, [file])
      EXEC [master].dbo.xp_DirTree @path,1,1;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t AS t WHERE t.subdirectory = @file)
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @error VARCHAR(100) = 
        'The source file, '+ISNULL(@sourceFile,'NULL')+' was not found.';
      PRINT @error;
      GOTO error
    END

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##import','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##import;
    CREATE TABLE ##import(Document VARCHAR(MAX));
  END

  -- 1. File Import
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Performing file import...';

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = 'INSERT INTO ##import(Document)
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'''+@sourceFile+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;';

    EXEC (@SQL);
  END

  -- 2. Transformation
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Performing file transform...';

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) = 
      N'SELECT STRING_AGG(s.item,CHAR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.ItemNumber)
        FROM   SQLToolbox_Misc.samd.delimitedSplitAB((SELECT i.Document FROM ##import AS i),CHAR(10)) AS s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STRING_SPLIT('''+@badText+''','','') AS ss 
                  WHERE CHARINDEX(ss.[value],s.item)>0);'

    SET @SQL = 'bcp '+'"'+@query+'" '+'queryout "'+@destFile+'" -c -T -S '+@@SERVERNAME;
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@sql,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'');

    DECLARE @SQLText VARCHAR(8000) = '  Executing:'+CHAR(10)+'  '+@SQL;
    PRINT @SQLText;

    EXEC [master]..xp_cmdshell @SQL;
    IF @cleanup = 1 DROP TABLE ##import;
  END

  error:
END
```

This code does something totally different but you can take note of how I:
1. Pull the file in using OPENROWSET
2. Do something to the contents (in my code I'm removing any "Bad Text" defined by @badText
3. Write a new file using BCP

Hope this helps.

Comment: If OP wants to remove the CR/LF from the end of the existing file, he can open it in NotePad, place his cursor at the end of the line, and press DEL a couple of times to delete the line terminator, and then Save.

Comment: Looking for a more automated solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @DavidDubois people will be shocked to discover that you can edit text using notepad. You should write a blog post on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you select "Save Results As" and select Text file, the result is a tab-delimited text file.  Each field is separated by tabs, and each record is terminated by a CR/LF.  There's no way of changing that by changing your query.

[image]

The text file generated is as follows:

[image]
The file starts with the byte-order-marker EF BB BF indicating it is UTF-8 format.  78, 79 and 7A are the 'x', 'y' and 'z'.  These are separated by TABs (09), and the record is terminated with CR/LF (OD/OA).  Then the same for the second record, also terminated by CR/LF.

On the other hand, you could select Copy, run NotePad, and Paste the text. You'll get CR/LFs between records, but none at the end.

[image]

Comment: Close, but still looking for a more automated solution as I have adTempus running this job each night.  Let me know if any other ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: So now you know that there's nothing you can change in your query to solve your problem. You can remove all those REPLACE's that are trying to remove them.  I don't know anything about adTempus, but I'm guessing if you can automate right-clicking, selecting a menu item and entering a file name, you can probably automate running Notepad and copy/pasting.  Or you can deal with the much smaller problem of simply finding a way to remove two bytes from the end of the file.  I'd bet there's some way to it with a DOS batch, or if not any developer could provide you with such in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better automated methods but to answer the question as posed, you can uncheck the box "Retain CR/LF on copy or save" found in the Op

Comment: Will this remove CR/LF from all lines?  I feel like it might.  I am only hoping to remove from the end of the trailer record line.  Sorry if I wasn't fully clear on that aspect of this.

Comment: Yes, it will.  I thought you only had a single row, but makes sense that you don't.